# Click on Groupcaption in LayoutView

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

i have an Xtragrid, where iam using a Layoutview. In my card i got two Groups with some content in it (no grouprow!). Is it possible to fire an click event, if the user click on the groupcaption?

It is a normal group! For Example select 3 textedits and then rightclick->group in the designer. The same you can do inside your cards of a layoutview.

regards.

Comment: Can you provide more information. I am not able to understand which group you are talking about.. attach a image of your grid and mark the group text that you are talking about..  If that item is part to CardView then it should be in Hit Test.. please elaborate your question more and clear.

Comment: I got the solution. It is not beautiful but it works :-p I get the Location in the mouse move event. In the gridview click event i check if the location is same like the groupcaption. This just works because my control got fixed size!

Comment: Edit your question and write your solution for future visitors.. try to write your question enough clear that another can understand. Well  have a nice day..

Comment: @Niranjan Kala It is just a normal Group. You can do if you select 3 textedit then rightclick -> group. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the View's MouseDown event handler and use HitTests to see if it's a Layout Item, then test the layout item to see if it's a group and check it's Border Info to get the caption bounds.

```
       LayoutView View = (sender as LayoutView);
        var hi = View.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
        if (hi.HitTest == LayoutViewHitTest.LayoutItem && hi.LayoutItem is DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlGroup)
        {
            var Border = (hi.LayoutItem.ViewInfo.BorderInfo as DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.GroupObjectInfoArgs);
            if (Border.CaptionBounds.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hit Group: " + Border.Caption);
                return;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Missed!");
```

Comment: Hey, thats good idea and i tried something like this but the problem is that the HitTest cant give me information about groups. Just cards, fields and much more.

Comment: @Sebi, I know you've worked it out but this might be a more general solution.

Comment: Awesome solution! I copy your way and its much better.

Comment: You have a solution for clicking a pictureedit instead of the Groupcaption. Its a repositoryitem and the click event dont fire :-(

Answer (score 0):

Get the mouseposition with the gridview mousemove event.

```
    private void grvReleaseInfo_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseLocation = e.Location;
    }
```

Then go to the click event of the gridview and check the mouseposition with the position of your item (groupcaption in my example)

```
private void grvReleaseInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((mouseLocation.X > 38) &&
                (mouseLocation.X < 85) &&
                (mouseLocation.Y > 46) &&
                (mouseLocation.Y < 117))
            {
                //Do sth.
            }
```

The mouselocation is variable of type "Point". If you dont know the Coordinates you can set breakpoint in debugger and watch the mouseposition if you click top-left corner of your item and then bottom-right corner. Then you have the range you have to check.

regards